# Controller not returning the view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've created a view which is inside the folder `userprofile`. I'm trying to show the view and when I enter the url it didn't gave me some error but it doesn't show anything, it stay on the same page.

This is my function in controller

```
public function viewChangePassword(){
    return view('userprofile.changepassword');
}
```

and the route

```
Route::get('/userprofile/changepassword','userProfileController@viewChangePassword');
```

Comment: have you checked that the route is hitting to the same method?

Comment: So if you open `/userprofile/changepassword` url in your browser, you'll see a blank page? Do you have any html in your view file? Also check your application log file for some possible errors.

Comment: how to check? when i check in cmd route:list it doesnt show the view changepassword, which is something nonspecific. As i know the route:list should show the view if its created.

Comment: @ArminSam yes i open and it doesnt redirect me to that page, as i mention i stay on the same page when i refresh the url.

Comment: what content you have in your view?

Comment: @Jaimin bootstrap form for changing password

Comment: maybe you are getting 500 error.. go to your terminal and navigate to your laravel installation directory and run sudo chmod -R 777 storage/ vendor/    after running this command try to call your route again, you'll see and error...

Comment: view: resources/views/userprofile/changepassword.blade.php ?

Comment: @IlyaYaremchuk yes like this

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to see if it works:

```
Route::get('userprofile/changepassword',
['uses' => 'userProfileController@viewChangePassword']);
```

If you have a href link to this route you should use:

```
Route::get('userprofile/changepassword',
    ['uses' => 'userProfileController@viewChangePassword','as' => 'change_password']);
```

and call it:

```
<a href="{{route('change_password'}}">Change Password</a>
```